# mariadb replication (master / slave) - slave lagging behind due to long execution on delete query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, replication

I have setup a pretty classic MariaDB 10.4.13 replication GTID setup with two servers (writable master and read only slave).

From some time I have noticed some inconsistencies in some of my application SELECT queries routed to slave.. After some troubleshooting I have seen that the slave's "Seconds_Behind_Master" value grow up to 10,000 seconds (!).

By doing a **SHOW PROCESSLIST** on the slave I noticed long queries like :

```
 11 | system user | | NULL | Slave_SQL | 14 | Delete_rows_log_event :: find_row (-1) | DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE` id` = 5580
```

and each one takes over 20+ seconds to perform (!) so they get accumulating and cause lagging...

The same delete queries launched on the master is instantaneous (0.031 sec.) - Moreover slave hardware is more powerful than master (4 core CPU vs 2 core CPU) and load average / CPU on the slave is very low.

I have already tried to increase the parallel "*slave_parallel_threads*" to the number of slave CPU (4)
as explained [here](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/goodbye-replication-lag/) but without any benefit.

Any clue on how to fix this or improve replication performance to keep master/slave in sync ?

Answer (score 0):

Is `DELETE FROM` mytable `WHERE` id `= 5580` the entire query?  (Except perhaps for the table name.)

Do you not have an index on `id`?

That should take only milliseconds if `id` is `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY`.

`slave_parallel_threads` -- Were the other threads touching the same table?

If you are deleting a large number of rows, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Perhaps a big `ALTER` was being performed on that table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, issue was due to poor table design in application.

Table was missing `UNIQUE / PRIMARY` keys, therefore `DELETE` queries on slave took ages as explained [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53375)

I fixed by creating a primary index on the table and rebuilding the SLAVE afterwards, no more lagging so far :)